# Install PyQt5 on Python 3.7 (Linux)

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.7, arm64

I would like to install PyQt5 module on my Python3.7 version. I have read a lots of topics and forum to know how to do.
Basicly three ways exists, pip install, ap-get install or tar folder.
For me, the good way was apt-get install with this command :

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5
```

python is my new version that I have updated on conf file to run on 3.7.

It say :

```
python-pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.7+dfsg-5)
```

But when I try to use it with :

```
python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Aug  2 2019, 09:14:49) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
>>>
```

However, when I run this command :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

```
python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5
>>>
```

It's good with Python3.5.3 but no for the newest version, I have use the same command to install on different version. And I don't know why the module doesn't import if the install command said me that I have been installed the PyQt5(5.7.1 version)

Comment: execute: `sudo python -m pip install pyqt5`

Comment: Thx for your answer. But I have already try to install with this way, that's why I have used apt-get install.

When I run this command an error happen :
Could not find a version...

Comment: Well it seems that you can not as you have tried, technically they are not the same, I do not understand why you do not want to use pip. Bye.

Comment: I already use pip to install module on Max OS, but on this OS the most pip install said me the same error :
Could not find version that satisfied the requirement...

So the other way it's to use sudo apt-get install like I have done

Comment: If you are using ubuntu or a similar distribution generally "python" points to python2 and "python3" points to python3 but in your case it is strange that "python" points to a more recent python3. How did you install the most recent "python"?

Comment: Ubuntu does not use the most recent versions of the libraries because Canonical does a previous test so the libraries it provides always have a delay of at least 3 months so it seems strange that you have installed python 3.7.3 with apt-get

Comment: With the offical web site and the tar folder. I have run configure.py make and make altinstall, because setup.py doesn't work in first place. After that I have seen a video to know how to put the lastest version in default command python.
So I have update the default conf file about python and modify his path to point on my new version.

Actually I running the pi64 OS on my Raspeberry Pi 3B Model +, and it work with aarch64 Linux.

Comment: You may not have correctly patched all paths, if you have installed compiling it since the tar then that reinforces that you should not use apt-get, I recommend 2 possibilities: 1) Uninstall the python-pyqt5 installed by apt-get and reinstall using the command that I pointed out O 2) create a virtualenv using python3 3.7.5 so you will not depend on apt-get or conflicts, I used the last option.

Comment: Okay, I will try the second option so. Thx for that. As far you know, the PyQt5.WebEngineWidget is compatible with aarch64 ? With Mac OS I have no problem to run an app with it, but on my Raspberry sound like I need to use the depreciate module WebKit to build a page.

Comment: To my knowledge it is not possible using apt-get or pip since QtWebEngine has not been compiled for the RPI architecture so you will have to compile it manually.